# angularjs ng-repeat TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null at after

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This code get me

```
 error angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null
    at after
```

after that I have add ngRepeat, can't understand what's going on. Intresting to know that error saing about self when I get response from get request and template has been rendered correct.

template

```
<ui-view ng-controller="VacansyContorller" class="layout-vacansy-list-view">
    <h4>Всего <% vacansyList.count %> <% ending %></h4>
    {# {% for vacansy in vacansy_list %} #}
    <div ng-if="vacansyList.count">
    <div ng-repeat="vacansy in vacansyList.results">
        <hr />
        <div class="vacansy-item">
            <h3 class="vacansy-title"><b><% vacansy.title %></b></h3>
            <span class="vacansy-about">
                <blockquote><% vacansy.short_text %></blockquote>
            </span>
            <div class="vacansy-container">
                <div class="vacansy-last-info-container">
                    <span class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <% vacansy.city %></span>
                    <span class="text-muted"><% vacansy.reward %> <i class="fa fa-usd" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="vacansy-creator-container">
                    <img class="vacansy-img" ng-if="vacansy.author.avatar" ng-src="<% vacansy.author.avatar %>">
                    <i ng-if="!vacansy.author.avatar" class="fa fa-user fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="text-primary vacansy-creator"><% vacansy.author.username %></span>
                    <span class="text-muted created-date-decorator"><small>Опубликовано</small></span>
                    <cite title="Source Title">    
                        <span class="vacansy-created-date"><% vacansy.created %></span>
                    </cite>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<ui-view/>
```

app.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var config = function($stateProvider, $interpolateProvider){
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');

        // $stateProvider.state({
        //     name: 'default',
        //     url: '/',
        //     templateUrl: 'static/main/index.html'
        // });
        // $stateProvider.state({
        //     name: 'test',
        //     url: '/test',
        //     template: '<h1>HELOQOWEQWEWQ</h1>'
        // });
    };

    var run = function(){

    };

    var JustDance = angular.module('JustDance', ['ui.router'])
        .config(['$stateProvider', '$interpolateProvider', config])
        .run([run]);

    JustDance.factory('vacansyFactory', function ($http, $q){
        this.getVacansyList = function(){            
            return $http.get('/vacansy/')
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.data
            });
        }
        return this;
    });

    JustDance.controller('VacansyContorller',
        ['$scope', '$http', 'vacansyFactory',
        function($scope, $http, vacansyFactory){
            $scope.vacansyList = [];

            $scope.getNumberEnding = function(number, words){
                number = number % 100;
                if (number >= 11 && number <= 19)
                    return words[2];
                number = number % 10;
                if (number == 1) {
                    return words[0];
                } else {
                    if (number == 2 || number == 3 || number == 4) {
                        return words[1];
                    } else {
                        return words[2];
                    }
                }
            }

            vacansyFactory.getVacansyList()
            .then(function(data){
                $scope.vacansyList = data;
                $scope.ending = $scope.getNumberEnding(data.count, ['предложение', 'предложения', 'предложений'])
            });
        }]
    );
})();
```

Thx for your attention.

Comment: can you give us a sample of vacansyList. I will try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: it's just a single item {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qwerqwer",
    "text": "qqqqqqqqqqqqqq\nqwerqwerqwer.",
    "short_text": "qqqqqqqqqqqqqq\nqwerqwerqwer....",
    "type": "Струнные",
    "author": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "candyboober",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "vacansy": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/vacansy/candyboober/",
        "avatar": ""
    },
    "city": "Любой город",
    "reward": 0,
    "created": "2016-09-21T18:50:03.595572Z"
}

Comment: count is just int param of this response, other is list of that items.

Comment: In ngRepeat, you are referencing something called vacansyList.results. I do not see the 'results' value in the data you provided.

Comment: it's just a json from my server, view generate by django_Rest_framework